# get eav attribute collection Code format in Magento2

Tags: magento2, eav-attributes, entities

I am migrating m1 code to m2, below is the code i used in m1 to get eav collection.

```
  $customerattrs = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getCollection();
    $customerattrs->addFieldToFilter('is_user_defined', 1);
    $customerattrs->addFieldToFilter('entity_type_id', Mage::getModel('eav/entity')->setType('customer')->getTypeId());
```

how this can be used in magento2?

here is my controller code

```
 class CreatePost extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
 {
protected $helperData;
public function __construct(

    \[Vendor}\[Module]\Helper\Data $helperData
) {
    $this->helperData = $helperData;
}    
public function execute()
{       
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

        $helderDataObj = $this->helperData- >getCustomerUserDefinedAttributes();
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($helderDataObj);            
        die;            
    }

  }

 }
```

I have declared helper file like below

```
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
 {
   protected $eavAttribute;
   protected $entity;   
   public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute $eavAttribute,
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity $entity
) {
    $this->eavAttribute = $eavAttribute;
    $this->entity = $entity;

    parent::__construct($context);
}
 public function getCustomerUserDefinedAttributes()
{
    $attributeCollection = $this->eavAttribute->getCollection();
    $attributeCollection->addFieldToFilter('is_user_defined', 1);
    $attributeCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_type_id',$this->entity->setType('customer')->getTypeId());

    return $attributeCollection;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add instance of Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute to the constructor of your class

```
protected $eavAttribute;
protected $entity;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute $eavAttribute,
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity $entity
    ...
){
    ...
    $this->eavAttribute = $eavAttribute;
    $this->entity = $entity;
    ...
}
```

and then use it like this.

```
$attributeCollection = $this->eavAttribute->getCollection();
$attributeCollection->addFieldToFilter('is_user_defined', 1);
$attributeCollection->addFieldToFilter(
    'entity_type_id',
    $this->entity->setType('customer')->getTypeId()
);
```

**UPDATE**

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \[Vendor}\[Module]\Helper\Data $helperData
) {
    $this->helperData = $helperData;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

Comment: Can we use it in controller?

Comment: Yes you can use it

Comment: hi, I am getting internal server error 
below is the error
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function dispatch() on null

Comment: Update your controller code in question

Comment: Please check it. I have updated in my question

Comment: Please check my updated answer you forget to add Context in construct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81150/discussion-between-jafar-and-rakesh-varma).

Comment: @RakeshVarma calling getCollection directly is deprecated. M2 best practice says you should use create an instance of the Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute (factory) and then call the getCollection method.

Comment: I think the `getCollection` it is deprecated now

Answer (score 3):

Since `getCollection` is deprecated, I would go this way:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\CollectionFactory as AttributeCollectionFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product as ProductEntityType;
use Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class ProductAttribute implements OptionSourceInterface
{
    /**
     * @var AttributeCollectionFactory
     */
    private $attributeFactory;

    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    private $eavConfig;

    /**
     * ProductAttribute constructor.
     *
     * @param AttributeCollectionFactory $attributeFactory
     * @param Config    $eavConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        AttributeCollectionFactory $attributeFactory,
        Config $eavConfig
    )
    {
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->attributeFactory = $attributeFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function toOptionArray() : array
    {
        $collection = $this->attributeFactory->create();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_type_id', $this->eavConfig->getEntityType(ProductEntityType::ENTITY)->getEntityTypeId());
        $attributeCodes = [];
        foreach($collection as $attributes)
        {
                $attributeCodes[] = [
                    'value' => $attributes->getData(AttributeInterface::ATTRIBUTE_CODE),
                    'label' => $attributes->getData(AttributeInterface::FRONTEND_LABEL)
                ];
        }
        return $attributeCodes;
    }
}
```

Same functionality with Object Manager:

```
   use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product as ProductEntityType;
   use Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeInterface;

   class ProductAttribute implements OptionSourceInterface
   {
    
   /**
   * @return array
   * @throws LocalizedException
   */
    public function toOptionArray() : array
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $attributeFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\CollectionFactory');
        $eavConfig = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
        $collection = $attributeFactory->create();
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_type_id', $eavConfig->getEntityType(ProductEntityType::ENTITY)->getEntityTypeId());      
        $attributeCodes = [];
        foreach($collection as $attributes)
        {
          $attributeCodes[] = [
            'value' => $attributes->getData(AttributeInterface::ATTRIBUTE_CODE),
            'label' => $attributes->getData(AttributeInterface::FRONTEND_LABEL)
        ];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much . it is so help full. the good thing about your method is that, it returns all attributes easily.

Comment: @moeinkh glad that it helped someone. Cheers ! :)